# Fast allocation of vectors of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, allocation

I store 3D data in a std::vector-based structure:

```
std::shared_ptr< std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< Type > > > > data;
```

I allocate this structure by calling resize while iterating through the vectors:

```
    arraydata.reset(new std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< Type > > >());
    arraydata->resize(m_width);
    for (unsigned int col_index = 0; col_index < m_width; ++col_index)
    {
        (*arraydata)[col_index].resize(m_height);
        for (unsigned int line_index = 0; line_index < m_height; ++line_index)
        {
            (*arraydata)[col_index][line_index].resize(m_nbbands);
        }
    }
```

But this allocation takes a lot of time when the dimensions are big...

Is there a way to allocate in a single operation all the needed space (with `malloc(m_width*m_height*m_nbbands*sizeof(Type))` for example) and then to assign to each vector its own data space in the global space ? Would it be more performant ?

---

**Edit**: I tested @justin-time's idea

```
    arraydata.reset(new std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< T > > >(m_width,
         std::vector< std::vector< T > >(m_height, std::vector< T > (m_nbbands))));
```

gives an execution time comparable to original code, around **4.9 s for allocation and 40 s for deallocation ???**

This can be seen in the memory manager:
[image]

I don't succeed in testing allocation from a malloc, this code fails at `std::vector< T > tmp(datptr, (T*)(datptr+arraySize));`

```
    unsigned int arraySize = m_nbbands*sizeof(T);
    T *datptr = (T*)malloc(m_width*m_height*arraySize);

    arraydata.reset(new std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< T > > >(m_width));
    for (unsigned int col_index = 0; col_index < m_width; ++col_index)
    {
        (*arraydata)[col_index].resize(m_height);
        for (unsigned int line_index = 0; line_index < m_height; ++line_index)
        {
            std::vector< T > tmp(datptr, (T*)(datptr+arraySize));
            (*arraydata)[col_index][line_index].swap(tmp);

            // also tested with same results:
            //(*arraydata)[col_index][line_index] = 
            //    std::vector< T >(datptr, (T*)(datptr+arraySize));

            datptr += arraySize;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try it, compare it, tell us.

Comment: Just allocate a 1d vector and use math to fake that it is a 3d vector.  That allows all of the memory to be allocated in one go.

Comment: Considering that `vector::resize()` adds elements if passed a value larger than size, you could probably also use [constructor #3 listed here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).  Not really sure if that would make it any faster, though, and I may be misreading something somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a vector of vector of vectors.  Use a class which has an internal array and then provides a way to access the elements.  For example:

```
template <typename T>
class vec3d {
    std::vector<T> data;
    size_t xmax, ymax, zmax;
public:
    T& operator()(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) 
                     { return data[x+y*xmax+z*xmax*ymax]; }
    const T& operator()(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) 
                     { return data[x+y*xmax+z*xmax*ymax]; }
    vec3d(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) 
                     : xmax(x), ymax(y), zmax(z), data(x*y*z) {}
    T& v(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) { return (*this)(x,y,z); }
 };
```

access would then be like

```
 shared_ptr<vec3d<int>> p = make_shared<vec3d<int>>(10, 20, 30);
 p->v(5,6,7) = 14;
```

or
     vec3d vec(5,6,7);
     vec(1,2,4) = 16.0f;  // Fortran style indexing.

You will probably want some more members to allow iteration, the dimensions, etc.  Because this is a single allocation, it will be *much* faster.

Comment: What bothers me is that I have a lot of existing accesses using the [x][y][z] syntax... Is it possible to keep this, maybe with intermediary objects ?

Comment: It is *possible*, but it's going to be fiddly.  `operator [](size_t x)` will have to return a proxy object which has an `operator [](size_t y)`  which either returns a float * (which can be indexed with z), or a second proxy which has `float & operator[](size_t z)`.  (The advantage of the second proxy is that you can range check z - the disadvantage is that it is yet more code to write).

Comment: Obviously you will need const and non-const versions of all the operators.

Comment: I followed your advice, allocation and deallocation now take less than a second. See answer below for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Following Martin Bonner's answer, I came to the following solution, for which allocation and deallocation take less than a second.

Data is accessible with `arraydata[x][y][z]`.

```
arraydata = std::make_shared< CImageStorage< T > >(m_width, 
    m_height, m_nbbands, bppixel);
```

with

```
template<class T>
class CImageStorage1D
{
    T* data;
    unsigned int m_nbbands;

public:
    CImageStorage1D(T* p, unsigned int nbbands) :
        data(p), m_nbbands(nbbands) {}

    T& DataPtr(unsigned int band) { return data[band]; }
    const T& DataPtr(unsigned int band) const { return data[band]; }
    T& operator[](unsigned int band) { return (data[band]); }
    const T& operator[] (unsigned int band) const { return (data[band]); }

    unsigned int size()const { return m_nbbands; }
};

template<class T>
class CImageStorage2D
{
    T* data;
    unsigned int m_height, m_nbbands, m_bppixel;

public:
    CImageStorage2D(T* p, unsigned int height, unsigned int nbbands,  
      unsigned int bppixel, std::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > heightShift) :
        data(p), m_height(height), m_nbbands(nbbands), m_bppixel(bppixel) {}

    T* DataPtr(unsigned int height) { return (T*)(data+m_height*m_nbbands); }
    const T* DataPtr(unsigned int height) const { 
        return (T*)(data+m_height*m_nbbands); }
    CImageStorage1D<T> operator[](unsigned int height) { 
        return CImageStorage1D<T>((T*)(data+m_height*m_nbbands), m_nbbands); }
    const CImageStorage1D<T> operator[] (unsigned int height) const { 
        return CImageStorage1D<T>((T*)(data+m_height*m_nbbands), m_nbbands); }

    unsigned int size()const { return m_height; }
};

template<class T>
class CImageStorage
{
    T* data;
    unsigned int m_width, m_height, m_nbbands, m_bppixel;

public:
    CImageStorage(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int nbbands, 
      unsigned int bppixel) :
        m_width(width), m_height(height), m_nbbands(nbbands), m_bppixel(bppixel)
    {
        data = (T*)malloc(m_width*m_height*m_nbbands*m_bppixel);
    }
    ~CImageStorage() { free(data); } 

    bool IsValid() { return (data != nullptr); }

    T** DataPtr(unsigned int width) { 
        return (T**)(data+width*m_height*m_nbbands); }
    const T** DataPtr(unsigned int width) const { 
        return (T**)(data+width*m_height*m_nbbands); }
    CImageStorage2D<T> operator[](unsigned int width) { 
        return CImageStorage2D<T>( (T*)(data+width*m_height*m_nbbands), 
            m_height, m_nbbands, m_bppixel); }
    const CImageStorage2D<T> operator[] (unsigned int width) const { 
        return CImageStorage2D<T>((T*)(data+width*m_height*m_nbbands), 
            m_height, m_nbbands, m_bppixel); }

    unsigned int size()const { return m_width; }
};
```